# ontouch in android: getting X and Y coordinates and drawing circle on that point

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, ontouchlistener

[image]

in my application on ontouch of screen i'm getting the coordinates(x.y),
after that on that position i'm drawing a circle.but when i'm drawing a circle on that position.it always draw a circle on upper left side corner of images on some pt.s .i'm not getting why this is happening.please help me.

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

               Log.d("position", event.getX() + "-" + event.getY());
                   System.out.println("bitmap......"+paths[0]+"draw...."+dd);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

                   paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow)) ;
                   paint.setAlpha(opacity);

                         // create canvas to draw on the bitmap
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutbit);
                    canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(),event.getY(), 10, paint);

                    im.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    im.setImageBitmap(mutbit);
                    dd[1]=im.getDrawable();
                    Bitmap aa=mutbit.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444,false);//mutbit=bb[tabCount].copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true);
                    bb[1]=aa;
                    return true;
                }
             return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
draw circle on Action down 
`event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

Comment: is it like- ' if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) ' . i tried this.its also not working

Comment: same condition as that person want.i want it in my activity class.

Comment: you are making costume view in Activity?

Comment: How to do this.actually i'm very new to all this.i want to draw a circle on image which is opened and again save it.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439456/how-to-create-a-simple-custom-view and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994621/eraser-is-not-called-when-button-is-pressed,   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOY2AxbnRyc